# Question about project organization - Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I am currently planning out a small project which will be a chrome extension. The idea is that when you are on youtube listening to a song, you can click on this extension, and it will search the song in Spotify and add it to a playlist. I know how to achieve this using python and synching your liked videos into Spotify playlists. However, what I want to achieve is to make a search, not from the liked videos but the video page itself, and eventually turn that into a chrome extension. I know that chrome extensions generally use js/Html so should I ditch using python for this project? Or is there a way I can use python as a "backend" of sorts for the chrome extension. Thanks!

Comment: Anything done in the browser would beed to be done using html/javascript. As for using python on a server or backend, that would probably add too much complication for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Extensions can launch a python app via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) but it'll be terribly clunky for a non-personal extension.